# Losing sessions when opening a new tab - ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this situation in ASP.NET MVC 5. After a user has logged in, I create some session variables like role, name and so on. The problem I'm having is that if I open a new tab I lose all those session variables. I do nothing in the new tab, I just click for the new tab and the application loses the session variables and if I refresh or clicked something in the existing tab, I'm redirected to the login page as if I have never logged in.

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: you mean a new browser tab, not some construct within your HTML? And when you say "loses the session", you mean the _existing_ tab loses its session and automatically redirects? I can't see how the application could detect this. Or do you mean the _new_ tab does not carry over the user session? Some browsers can be configured to sandbox each tab so that it runs in a separate session - often done via a plugin. So probably it's the config of the specific browser, not your application.

Comment: ADyson: The existing tab loses the sessions when I open a new one and when I click a button or refresh it redirects me to the Login Page. -----
 mjwills:
I have added some photos and explanations of my problem.

Comment: Are you storing the session in a cookie, if you're just creating it on the page then obviously it won't persist between tabs.

Comment: Ryan McDonough: I'm losing the sessions in my existing tab when I open a new one.

Comment: " the application has 3 sessions already created."...there can only be one server-side session per browser session. The "count" property counts the number of session _variables_ within the session object, not the number of sessions. So possibly your session variables are being cleared somehow, but this is not (necessarily) the same as the session being ended. And there's no way for your app to know that the user clicked the "new tab" button - this is a browser action only, and is private to the user. Your app cannot and should not know about that. I think what you've seen is a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of session object and session variables ADyson. As of now I have seen this is only happening in Firefox. I have changed the validation to be able to check all these session variables to avoid any problems, thank you very much.